# Pop off array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I've got a string array in C# and I want to pop the top element off the array (ie. remove the first element, and move all the others up one). Is there a simple way to do this in C#? I can't find an Array.Pop method.

Would I need to use something like an ArrayList? The order of the items in my array is important.

Comment: Is your collection guaranteed to have content? Most of the Queue and Stack suggestions below assume so. Queues and Stacks in C# throw exceptions if you try to `Dequeue` or `Pop` off an empty collection.

Comment: Added a SafeQueue implementation to handle empty collections

Comment: You can use Linq: `array.Skip(1).ToArray()`;

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), [Queue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) or [Stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) instead..

```
List<String>
Queue<String>
Stack<String>
```

Comment: I dont see a Pop function in the documentation of those types, except the Stack.

Comment: While the suggestion is fair, I don't think this answers the question; how to pop the first element off an array. At least maybe you should have shown how to do it with a List etc.

Comment: see my answer below to cut the superfluous

Comment: Please also answer the question

Comment: After a few years I just came back here by accident and now I'm realizing that I've outperformed @jon-skeet on this specific question. I'll put that on my grave stone.

Comment: What if I am not in control of the `Type`? The alternative for arrays is to use Linq: `array.Skip(1).ToArray();`

Answer (score 34):

[`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx) (first in, first out) or [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx) (last in, first out) are what you're after.

Arrays in .NET are fixed length - you can't remove an element from them or indeed add elements to them. You *can* do this with a `List<T>` but `Queue<T>` and `Stack<T>` are more appropriate when you want queue/stack semantics.

Comment: Hey Jon, Any chance we can get IQueue or IStack interfaces defined which are implemented in the existing semantics? I'd like to write "safe" versions that will just return default(T) when the collection is empty.

Comment: @MichaelBlackburn: If you're asking whether there are interfaces already in the framework - no, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: OK, I just wrote a derived SafeQueue class that `new`s the Dequeue and Peek methods and lets everything else pass through, didn't even take that long. I find this pattern useful for passing arguments from main Programs to component modules; take string[] args and each component takes its parameters and passes the others through. It's just annoying to have it blow up when there are no parameters.

Answer (score 15):

From MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class MSDNSample
    {
       static void Main()
       {
          string input = "a b c d";

          Stack<string> myStack = new Stack<string>(
             input.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None));

          // Remove the top element (will be d!)
          myStack.Pop();

          Queue<string> myQueue = new Queue<string>(

          input.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.None));

          // Remove the first element (will be a!)
          myQueue.Dequeue();

       }
    }
}
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharplanguage/thread/a924097e-3d72-439d-984a-b371cd10bcf4/

Comment: The problem with stack is that myStack.ToArray will be d,c,b,a

Answer (score 9):

Since we have ***linq*** is very easy to do:

```
string[] array = ...;
array = array.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely possible in Array, but it is not efficient.  You literally have to shift down your array using a loop and setting arr[i] = arr[i+1] in a for loop.  After this, if you want, you have to resize the array.

Because of these caveats, array isn't the best data structure to deal with problem.  Array is best for static data, or data whose size will not change.

Since you want to remove data, array is clearly not the answer.  Specifically, you want to pop the first/top element from your collection, and there is already an efficient data structure that does this: [Stack](http://www.dotnetperls.com/stack).

This is the beauty of data structures, they give you an efficient way to deal with your collections based on what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2):

What you actually want is called a Queue, you can create a Queue from your Array like so:

```
var args = { "value1", "value2" };
var queue = new Queue<string>(args);
var arg1 = queue.Dequeue();
var arg2 = queue.Dequeue();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the concern I noted above but had problems with Queue's default behavior of throwing an exception when the collection was empty (not really an exceptional situation). This is my implementation of a SafeQueue, which will defer most operations to the base class, but implements new `Dequeue()` and `Peek()` operations that return `default(T)` if the queue is empty. In cases where it is possible `default(T)` was added to the queue (unlikely for object types, but very likely for value types), it is impossible to tell if the queue is empty just with `Peek`. A new `IsEmpty` property makes it possible to tell when you're done.

```
public class SafeQueue<T>: Queue<T>
{
    public SafeQueue() : base() { }

    public SafeQueue(int count) : base(count) { }

    public SafeQueue(IEnumerable<T> collection) : base(collection) { }

    public bool IsEmpty {get { return Count == 0; }}

    public new T Dequeue()
    {
        return IsEmpty ? default(T) : base.Dequeue();
    }

    public new T Peek()
    {
        return IsEmpty ? default(T) : base.Peek();
    }
}


[TestClass]
public class SafeQueueTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeQueue_int_constructor_works()
    {
        var q = new SafeQueue<string>(5);
        Assert.IsNotNull(q);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("a");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("b");
        Assert.AreEqual(2, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("c");
        Assert.AreEqual(3, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("d");
        Assert.AreEqual(4, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("e");
        Assert.AreEqual(5, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("f");
        Assert.AreEqual(6, q.Count);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeQueue_dequeue_works()
    {
        var q = new SafeQueue<string>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(q);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("a");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("b");
        Assert.AreEqual(2, q.Count);
        var result = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual("a", result);
        result = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual("b", result);
        result = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual(null, result);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeQueue_peek_works()
    {
        var q = new SafeQueue<string>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(q);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("a");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, q.Count);
        var result = q.Peek();
        Assert.AreEqual("a", result);
        result = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual("a", result);
        result = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual(null, result);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeQueue_isEmpty_works()
    {
        var q = new SafeQueue<string>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(q);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, q.Count);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, q.IsEmpty);
        q.Enqueue("content");
        Assert.AreEqual(false, q.IsEmpty);
        var result2 = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual("content", result2);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, q.IsEmpty);
        result2 = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, q.IsEmpty);
        Assert.AreEqual(null, result2);
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeQueue_passedThroughQueueOperationContains_work()
    {
        var q = new SafeQueue<string>(5);
        Assert.IsNotNull(q);
        Assert.AreEqual(0, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("a");
        Assert.AreEqual(1, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("b");
        Assert.AreEqual(2, q.Count);
        q.Enqueue("c");
        Assert.AreEqual(3, q.Count);
        Assert.IsTrue(q.Contains("a"));
        Assert.IsFalse(q.Contains("asdfawe"));
        var outval = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.IsFalse(q.Contains("a"));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void SafeQueue_CantTellByDequeueIfQueueIsEmptyOrContainsNull()
    {
        var q = new SafeQueue<string>();
        Assert.IsNotNull(q);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, q.IsEmpty);
        q.Enqueue(null);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, q.IsEmpty);
        var result2 = q.Peek();
        Assert.AreEqual(null, result2);
        Assert.AreEqual(false, q.IsEmpty);
        result2 = q.Dequeue();
        Assert.AreEqual(true, q.IsEmpty);
        Assert.AreEqual(null, result2);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree on the above, but I have a little enhancement..

```
  public static class ArrayExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the last element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="array">The array.</param>
        /// <returns>T[].</returns>
        public static T[] RemoveLastElement<T>(this T[] array)
        {
            var stack = new Stack<T>(array);
            stack.Pop();
            return stack.ToArray().Reverse().ToArray();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the first element.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="array">The array.</param>
        /// <returns>T[].</returns>
        public static T[] RemoveFirstElement<T>(this T[] array)
        {
            var queue = new Queue<T>(array);
            queue.Dequeue();
            return queue.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

And to make it complete, here is the test:

```
  [Test]
        public void ExtensionsTests_ArrayExtensionTests()
        {
            var data = new[] { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

            Assert.AreEqual("BCD", string.Join("", data.RemoveFirstElement()));
            Assert.AreEqual("ABC", string.Join("", data.RemoveLastElement()));
        }
```

Comment: Isn't reversing the array a bit non-performant? If the array is a million values, you're doing a hellofa lot more work than just did `array[array.Length-1];`

Comment: Creating Queues or Stacks are expensive hits for sure.. But your example is doing no better saying array[array.Length-1]; will also do the same expensive operation or allocating new big locations in memory. However maybe you meant using Buffer.Copy or Array.Copy with the correct parameters then that might improve performance; We need some metrics.

Comment: While I am all about using metrics above supposition, I feel pretty confident taking an item by index is quicker than sorting the entire array. An item by index is O(1), and even if the array is shifted to a new location, it's O(n) complexity. Sorting is at best O(n logn)

Comment: Uh, brain fart. You're not sorting, you're reversing the array, which is going to be about the same as copying it. `New`ing the Stack and Queue objects is the long pole in the tent.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, this is also fast;

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Pop value from top of string[] array
    /// </summary>
    public void PopStringArray(ref string[] array)
    {
        int newLength = array.Length;
        string[] temp = new string[array.Length];

        for (int i = array.Length - 1; i >= 1; i--)
            temp[i - 1] = array[i];

        array = temp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone comes across this, pop()-function that resembles the one in typescript, i.e. pop last item off array and return its value

```
    public static T Pop<T>(this IList<T> collection) where T : class
    {
        if (collection == null || !collection.Any())
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Failed to pop list of {typeof(T)}, cannot be empty or null");
        }

        var lastItemAsJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(collection.Last());
        collection.Remove(collection.Last());
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(lastItemAsJson);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This wrapper will be help you. Its might be addressing the your solution.

```
class ArrayStack<T>  {
    List<T> _list;
    public int Count => _list.Count;
    public T this[ int index ] {
        get {
            int count = _list.Count;
            if ( ( uint )index >= ( uint )count ) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( nameof( index ), "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" );
            }
            return _list[ index ];
        }
        set {
            int count = _list.Count;
            if ( ( uint )index >= ( uint )count ) {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException( nameof( index ), "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" );
            }
            _list[ index ] = value;
        }
    }
    public ArrayStack( ) {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }
    public void Push( T item ) {
        _list.Add( item );
    }
    public T Shift( ) {
        if ( _list.Count == 0 ) {
            // no element found
            return default( T );
        }
        T item = _list[ 0 ];
        _list.RemoveAt( 0 );
        return item;
    }
    public T Pop( ) {
        int lastIndex = _list.Count - 1;
        if( lastIndex < 0 ) {
            // no rest of element
            return default( T );
        }
        T item = _list[ lastIndex ];
        _list.RemoveAt( lastIndex );
        return item;
    }
}
```

and use

```
ArrayStack<int> array = new ArrayStack<int>( );
array.Push( 10 ); // add new item
array.Push( 11 ); // add new item
array.Push( 12 ); // add new item
int item = array[ 0 ]; // 10
item = array.Shift( ); // 10; remove and get first item
item = array.Pop( ); // 12; remove and get last item
```